# How to assume timestamp is MST (US/Mountain) instead of UTC

Tags: timezone, pipeline, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I'm am building a pipeline in Data Fusion where we use the Database Plugin to ingest data from our on-prem Oracle DB and insert into a BigQuery table. The Database Plugin correctly infers `timestamp` data types for date fields in our Oracle tables. The issue is, however, that the date fields are actually in MST timezone. Data Fusion, however, assumes they are in UTC.

Ex: Date in on-prem DB is `Mar 11, 2020, 5:45:40 AM MST` and it comes up as `Mar 11, 2020, 5:45:40 AM UTC` in BigQuery.

In the pipeline, I am using the Wrangler Plugin to transform column data types using directives. I tried using the `parse-as-date DATE_COLUMN US/Mountain` directive, but it did not work.

I have asked GCP support if there's a way to set default Data Fusion timezone to MST. I'm asking here to see if there's a way to do it with Plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to set MST as the default time zone in Data Fusion; however, I tried to replicate the scenario and I was able to use `parse-as-date DATE_COLUMN MST` to parse the column and insert it into BigQuery with the correct time in UTC `Mar 11, 2020, 11:45:40 AM UTC`.

Comment: i tried using your directives and it didn't change anything. my pipeline does, however, output to GCS in addition to BQ. looking at the file in GCS i see a unix timestamp in date columns. For the date column that is supposed to be `Aug 8, 2019, 11:00:24 AM MST`, the file in GCS has `1565262024000000` -- which appears to be microsecond version of `Aug 8, 2019, 11:00:24 AM UTC`. I feel like i need to use the `format-unix-timestamp` directive but not sure what pattern to use

Comment: Yes, when you use the directive, the new column is a timestamp in Unix format. This value is the one that you need to insert into BigQuery as timestamp

Comment: But the timestamp value is being inserted into BQ and is still being read in as UTC instead of realizing it's MST. `Aug 8, 2019, 11:00:24 AM UTC` is what I see in BQ

Comment: I misread your previous comment. If the Unix timestamp is not correct, then the parsing isn't working, as you pointed out. Can you share an image of the Wrangler with the column before and after the parse-as-date ?

Comment: so i actually can't use the Wrangler UI for my application because for some reason it doesn't work with a Data Source that's Oracle Plugin. It's a long story. Basically I can use Wrangler plugin within Pipeline when it's deployed, but that's it. It sounds like I have to do something in the sql query to convert to UTC prior to ingest

Comment: I see, so, have you been able to see/log the format of the timestamp after the oracle plugin? I've made some tests, but I get the correct MST time zone

Comment: Yea so pipeline works only when Deployed but can't use it in Preview or use Wrangler UI. When I look at data after running pipeline with suggested Wrangler directives it doesn't correctly assume MST timezones. I have been using workarounds by ingesting timestamps as strings and parsing as dates within BQ.

Comment: So, I've been trying with different transformations. I think that the most flexible solution is using the Javascript transform. The timestamp comes as number, and you can modify it accordingly as needed. Another option is to continue using one of the parse directives in the wrangler but how you use them depends on how you're reading the date from the db. Finally, to try the wrangler UI, you can create a sample file with content similar to what you're going to read and put it into Storage. Then you can use Wrangler UI to play around it and see the transformations.

Comment: Yes it seems only option is to do one of the many possible workaround. I am ingesting te timestamp as a string with timezone and parsing it later as a timestamp. Maybe someday BQ will allow one to change default timezone.